# Event Callbacks with Threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have a class B (implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged) that monitors for events.  It sits inside a class A that receives the event notifications.  The events class B generates can often be very frequent, so I'd like to:

1. Run the code for class A on a thread ThA (not interacting with containing class, B)
2. Run the code for class B on a thread ThB, and when an event occurs, before notifying the containing class A of the event (by doing an invoke on the dispatcher for ThA?), it checks that ThA is not in use by class A.  This way, I would keep it so that only ThA runs inside A, and also avoid overwhelming ThA with notifications from class B (info from class B will create events for class A "only when ThA has time").

So it might look something like this -

```
public class A
{
     private B b
     private Thread ThA

     public A
     {
         b= new B(ThA);
         b.PropertyChanged+=..
     }

     Event1 callback running on ThA
     Event2 callback running on ThA
     Callback for b (invoked in ThA)
}

public class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       private Thread ThA
       private Thread ThB

       public B(ThA_)
       {
            ThA=ThA_;
       }

       private void EventInClassB_Updated(object sender, Args e)
       {
            if (ThA is not being used for anything)
            {
                DispatcherForThreadA.invoke( notifyPropertyChanged() ); //send the callback to class A
            }
       }

}
```

Does anyone know if there is a smarter way to do this, and if not, how I might encode "ThA is not being used for anything"?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: btw, subsrubing for event in constructor is a **BAD** thing in multhithreded environment: you are exposing your non-constructed object to external world, which can use it at the same time!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) or a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to control access to ThA. Simply call `Monitor.TryEnter` to get the lock. If `TryEnter` fails, then ThA is in use. Be sure to call `Monitor.Exit` when ThA is done.

The code for using a `Mutex` would be similar. In general, the `Monitor` will perform better, but it can't be used across app domain boundaries.